# pass a value from jsf to php

Tags: php, jsf

I have a JSF application which I'd like to integrate with a PHP based document repository. Integration should work in a way that, when a tender is selected in my JSF application, the list of documents associated with that tender (gathered from the PHP based document respository) should be listed, communication would be done using the tender identifier (`tenderId`).

Today, I am forcing the user to manually enter the `tender id`, but I would rather pass the `tender id` to the php page directly. If the user selects a tender on the JSF and clicks the document repository link, the resulting link should inform the PHP script which `tender id` the user just left from the JSF side. Basically, I want to know how to pass a value from JSF to PHP dynamically.

I can pass a value in URL but, how to get the value in PHP is what I actually require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a value to a PHP script via the URL, you can find it in the super-global variable $_GET. See [the documentation on $_GET](http://php.net/%24_GET) for specifics.

Comment: ok, it was very helpful. But what happens is i am trying to pass a string variable. instead of getting the value out of string it displays string itself . am i missing something.

Comment: sorry ,to be clear i am trying to pass a value by assigning it to a string variable. But instead of getting vallue out of the string , the function displays the  variable itself

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say here, sorry; can you provide some source code that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: Sure,     ' <p:commandButton  action="#{docManagedBean.addDocs(action)}"

                                              value="Upload Documents">
   <f:param name="tenderId" value="#{tenderStagesManagedBean.tenderInfo.tenderId}"  />
                            </p:commandButton>' This command button will invoke my method.

Comment: and my method is        public void addDocs(ActionEvent action) throws IOException{
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); 
tenderid=context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap().get("tenderId");
System.out.println("tenderTrackingNumber for add "+tenderid);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("http://localhost:89
/kordil_edms/documents_add.php?id='tenderid'");
} where i am getting the tender id and passing it to the URL. In my php, 
<?php
echo ($_GET["id"]) ;
?>
Instead of displaying the value from id. it displays \tenderid\.

Comment: redirect("localhost:89/kordil_edms/documents_add.php?id='tenderid'"); 

needs to be
    redirect("localhost:89/kordil_edms/documents_add.php?id="+tenderid);